# I want to call a function that requieres parametes from a click on a link using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new with JQuery and sorry if this is so dump...

I have this site (on my computer)
[image]

I created with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Finder</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    $('#submitform').click(function(){
        var action =  $(this).parent().attr('action');
        action += '&query=' + $(this).parent().find('input[name="query"]').val() + '&language=es' ;
        //window.location.href = action;
        $("#PageSelector td").parent().remove();
        $("#userdata td").parent().remove();

        $.getJSON(action, function(data) {
                var myNext = action + "&page=" + parseInt(parseInt(data.page) + 1)      //https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=1ca8226c006afb25adc4c816a2f8c184&query=black&language=es&page=2 (Next Page)
                var myPrev = action + "&page=" + parseInt(parseInt(data.page) - 1)  //https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=1ca8226c006afb25adc4c816a2f8c184&query=black&language=es&page=0 (Previous page)
                var myNextLink
                var myPrevLink
                if (parseInt(data.page) >= parseInt(data.total_pages)) {
                    myNextLink = "___"
                } else {
                    myNextLink = "<a id= &#34;NextPage&#34;  href=" + myNext + "    class=&#34;call-btn&#34;>       &gt;&gt;&gt;          </a>"  //here is where i have the link to renew the table
                    }
                if (parseInt(data.page) <= parseInt(1)) {
                    myPrevLink = "___"
                } else {
                    myPrevLink = "<a id= &#34;PrevPage&#34;  href=" + myPrev + "    class=&#34;call-btn&#34;>       &lt;&lt;&lt;          </a>"  //here is where i have the link to renew the table
                    }                   
                var nPage = "<tr>" + "<td> Número Página: " + parseInt(parseInt(data.page)) + myPrevLink + "____" + myNextLink + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                var tResults = "<tr>" + "<td> Total Resultados: " + data.total_results + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                var tPage = "<tr>" + "<td> Número Página: " + data.total_pages + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(nPage).appendTo("#PageSelector tbody");
                $(tPage).appendTo("#PageSelector tbody");
                $(tResults).appendTo("#PageSelector tbody");
        });

        $.getJSON(action, function(data) {
            $.each(data.results, function(i, f) {
                var myPic = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + f.poster_path 
                var myBac = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + f.backdrop_path 
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" 
                + f.vote_count + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.id + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.vote_average + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.popularity + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + "<img src=" + myPic + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.original_language + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.original_title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.genre_ids + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + "<img src=" + myBac + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.adult + "</td>" + "<td>"    
                + f.overview + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.release_date + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");  
            });
        });
    });
});


    //Here are my function... that does not work!
$(".call-btn").click(function(aLink){   
    $("#userdata td").parent().remove();
    $.getJSON(aLink, function(data) {
        $.each(data.results, function(i, f) {
            var myPic = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + f.poster_path 
            var myBac = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + f.backdrop_path 
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" 
            + f.vote_count + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.id + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.vote_average + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.popularity + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + "<img src=" + myPic + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.original_language + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.original_title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.genre_ids + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + "<img src=" + myBac + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.adult + "</td>" + "<td>"    
            + f.overview + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.release_date + "</td>" + "</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");  
        });
    });     
});


</script>
<body>
<!-- Form part -->
<!-- bdd8feef -->
<!-- http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0978762&apikey=bdd8feef -->
<!-- 1ca8226c006afb25adc4c816a2f8c184 -->
<!-- https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=1ca8226c006afb25adc4c816a2f8c184 -->
<!-- https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=1ca8226c006afb25adc4c816a2f8c184&query=star+wars&page=1 -->
<!-- Just a button <button type="button">Click Me!</button> -->
<h2>Video</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <form action="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=1ca8226c006afb25adc4c816a2f8c184" method="post" target="_blank">
          Buscar:<br>
          <input type="text" name="query" value="black">
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="button" id="submitform">Submit</button>
        </form> 
        <br><br><br>
<table id="PageSelector">
<thead>
</thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
        <table id= "userdata" border="2">
            <thead>
                <th>Total de votos</th>
                <th>Id TMDB</th>
                <th>Video</th>
                <th>Promedio de votos</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Popularidad</th>
                <th>Poster</th>
                <th>Lenguaje original</th>
                <th>Titulo Original</th>
                <th>Generos</th>
                <th>Background</th>
                <th>Para Adultos</th>
                <th>Sinopsis</th>
                <th>Fecha de lanzamiento</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, when the user click `Submit` the user get this:

[image]

Each page is a list of 20 item of N, and could be N pages, and I need to set a "`Page Selector`" with the "`>>>`" to go to every page of the Items list (20 by 20)

What i want is to set the link with the "`>>>`" to renew the table, with the next 20 items in the query.

Heres is my failure...

```
    //Here are my function... that does not work!
$(".call-btn").click(function(aLink){   
    $("#userdata td").parent().remove();
    $.getJSON(aLink, function(data) {
        $.each(data.results, function(i, f) {
            var myPic = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + f.poster_path 
            var myBac = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + f.backdrop_path 
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" 
            + f.vote_count + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.id + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.vote_average + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.popularity + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + "<img src=" + myPic + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.original_language + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.original_title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.genre_ids + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + "<img src=" + myBac + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.adult + "</td>" + "<td>"    
            + f.overview + "</td>" + "<td>" 
            + f.release_date + "</td>" + "</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");  
        });
    });     
});
```

But i do not know how to call that function (in case is ok...) from here:

```
"<a id= &#34;NextPage&#34;  href=" + myNext + "    class=&#34;call-btn&#34;>        &gt;&gt;&gt;          </a>"  //here is where i have the link to renew the table
```

With that string I create a `<a href:"url" class="call-btn"> link </a>` trying that the user just go to the next page of the items, but does not work.

Here is the seudo code that i want:

```
<a href="url" onclick="myFunction(url)"> link </a>



myFunction(url){
        //to recreate the table using the JSON file
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data.results, function(i, f) {
                var myPic = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + f.poster_path 
                var myBac = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + f.backdrop_path 
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" 
                + f.vote_count + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.id + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.vote_average + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.popularity + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + "<img src=" + myPic + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.original_language + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.original_title + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.genre_ids + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + "<img src=" + myBac + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.adult + "</td>" + "<td>"    
                + f.overview + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                + f.release_date + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");  
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Script tags should be in the `<head>` or the `<body>`. It's invalid to have them anywhere else. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` to avoid href behavior:

```
myFunction(event, url) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: `href="#"`, not `href:"#"`, although I don't think this will address the problem in any way

Comment: I Just did... `myNextLink = "<a id= &#34;NextPage&#34;  href=#" + " onclick=&#34;myFunction(myNext)&#34;> &gt;&gt;&gt; </a>"` and now does do anythig...

Comment: Use prevent default to aviid hreg redirection

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like changing `onclick="myFunction(url)"` to `onclick="return myFunction(this)"`  and then your method could do something like

```
myFunction(link){
    //to recreate the table using the JSON file
    //link.href is the href on the <a> clicked
    $.getJSON(link.href, function(data) {
        ...
    });

    //return false to cancel the link processing
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Uh, don't try to put your own code in my answer man.  Put it in on your question or link to it.

Comment: Sorry, just want to show you, but wont happen again. Just looking for help.

Comment: Can you share what you had that isn't working, in your question, or on a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Here is my code:   [link](https://codeshare.io/amNKE1) Just copy on txt save it with .HTML and run it, click `SUBMIT` button and press `>>>`

Comment: What i want is to see the page #2 when the user press `>>>`

Comment: Wait, so are you doing inline bindings or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170570/discussion-between-taplar-and-elbert-villarreal).

Comment: I get a `JSON` file from server, and in that file comes the info that I need to create what you see, and when the user want to go to the page 2 with `>>>` I recreate the link (and take it from the same serer( and add a parameter (`&page=2`) to got to the next page,